# Hacking Xodus file storage mechanism to deploy to Heroku or Openshift

Tags: java, heroku, openshift, byte-buddy, xodus

What are the consequences (or issues that I might face) if I try to hack Xodus File I/O, as such I will use ByteBuddy to replace all access to Java File I/O and that Xodus will actually "persist" to that interface instead of the disk I/O, since I find it inefficient (and almost impossible) to have persistent storage on cloud platforms (Heroku, Openshift to names a few)--so this hack I am thinking is to create my own Java File I/O that instead of saving to disk it will save to a more elastic storage, such as Google Cloud Storage, S3 and other Object storage. So that I can run my app in Heroku or Openshift.

Will there be a side-effect with Xodus if I replace the File I/O with ByteBuddy or Xodus database is agnostic about it?

Answer (score 2):

For a cleaner approach, you should refactor to using the NIO2 `FileSystem` abstraction and then use the file system you intended to use. At the same time, I understand that this is not always possible.

If you wanted to replace the `File` API, the simplest way would probably be to redefine the `File` class to implement operations in the way you wanted to. Have a look at the `AgentBuilder` API for this and use  `RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORM`.

When redefining the `File` class, you can use `Advice` which inlines the code of templates and also allows you to override implementations. In this case, you can use `Advice` as an interceptor:

```
builder = builder.method(...).intercept(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class));
```

where you control the implementation, typically from an exit advice where you can set return values as follows:

```
class MyAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodExit
  void exit(@Advice.Return(readOnly = false) Void value) {
    value = ...;
  }
}
```

If you want to leave parts of the `File` API intact, you can also use advice as decorator:

```
builder = builder.visit(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class).on(...));
```

where you can determine if the original method should be executed from an enter method.

Comment: When you replace the File API for example does it replace across the whole application lifecycle? For example for a web application does it replace every call (e.g. calls from other libraries that may need to actually  write to file for boostrapping etc.) or just for specific packages?

Comment: It rewrites the code as if you actually programmed it that way. What classes it affects depends on how you set up the `type` step matcher and the `ignore` statement.